# How to calculate group_concat in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, group-concat

I want to groupconcat product name..but it displaying undefined index product name in my view page..I don't know where i am making mistake..please help me to groupconcat product name..

controller code:

```
$this->db->select('GROUP_CONCAT(prdtname)', false);
$this->db->from('purchaseitem');
$this->db->group_by('vno');
$query1=$this->db->get()->row_array();
$data['query1']= $query1;
```

I tried groupconcat in sql on my localhost it gives me an expected result..but i don't know where i had done mistake in converting to codeigniter..please help me to resolve this..

Comment: did u try this?  $this->db->select(GROUP_CONCAT(prdtname SEPARATOR ","), false);

Comment: You may encounter cases where either CI or MySQL are stricter in terms of how to build queries. If, for example, your db server was in strict mode it could be the case that: 1. Group concat requires that it's not the only field in the select (try select vno, group_contact....) And 2. Group by must be a field that's present in the select clause (in non strict modes you can group by something that's not explicitly in the clause, but in strict modes you can't)

Comment: Yes sir..i figure it out my mistake..thanks for your response..:)

Comment: Also, try giving the group contact generated field an alias... It makes it easier to handle later. Try `group_concat(prdtname) as alias` so you can use the result with less difficulty

Comment: Yes sir..tried this one and got answer..thank you for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller Code:

```
$this->db->select('GROUP_CONCAT(prdtname)as itemname',false);
$this->db->from('purchaseitem');
$this->db->group_by('vno');
```

View page:

```
<td><?=$row['itemname'];?></td>
```